# Powering BLDC motors using a Li-po battery

Tags: dc-dc-converter, brushless-dc-motor, lipo

I'm building a self-balancing cube using 3 reaction wheels much like the Cubli but smaller. I'm a mechanical engineering student with not a lot of electronics experience other than the basics.
The project will consist of 3 EC 45 flat 30 W BLDC motors from Maxon and a [controller](https://www.maxongroup.com/maxon/view/product/367661) also from Maxon.

I'm planning on using a Li-po battery because of their high output current. The motors are 2 A nominal each and I estimate the total maximum current to be 8 A including electronics.

The controllers can handle a voltage between 8 and 24 VDC. The motors are 12 V so I am guessing the controller contains some buck-boost converter. The datasheet does not say anything about this.

My questions are:

1. Would this require any other components like converters between the battery and the controllers? Or will it be sufficient to just wire the battery directly to the controllers with maybe a fuse?
2. I selected a 3s1p Li-po battery with 11.1 V. would it be better to get more cells for a higher voltage since the motors are 12 V?

Comment: 11.1 to 12V will take about 7% off the motor's top speed. Practically, it'll be fine.

Comment: 3s batteries are charged when terminal voltage hits 12.6v.. Now then, following the youtube channel Applied Science, I discovered that the speed controllers used by the hobby market are now very easy to re-flash with a new program. There's lots of source-code available for the devices. He used the motor to make a spin-coating machine. Details are in the video. The reason I mention hobby ESCs is price. They're a bucket-load cheaper than that Maxon device and can handle much more current. I've got a 35 amp one here, for which I paid about AUD $15.

Comment: As for batteries, I've got some 130mAh LiPo cells here that give about 5.2 amps for short bursts and can happily go from full to flat in 6 mins at a discharge rate of about 1.3A.  These cells are 39x7x10.5mm and weigh 4 grams. If you want cheap - use 3 18650 cells. DO NOT buy Lithium cells unless you have or purchase a charger designed for them. 20 or 30 bucks'll do it. I've got an IMAX B6 copy. It charges virtually anything rechargeable. Handy for the car and the cordless drill too.

Answer (score 1):

> The controllers can handle a voltage between 8 and 24 VDC. The motors are 12 V so I am guessing the controller contains some buck-boost converter. The datasheet does not say anything about this.

Very likely the controller does not have a buck-boost in it, at least to power the motor.  Far more likely is that there's a regulator down to 12V or 5V to power its electronics, but it would be just a buck, or a linear regulator.

> Would this require any other components like converters between the battery and the controllers? Or will it be sufficient to just wire the battery directly to the controllers with maybe a fuse?

Just a fuse should be sufficient.  Depending on how the controllers are designed, you may want to keep the battery leads short (if you got RC batteries, and if you keep the plug that came on the battery, just make up a pigtail for the controller that's about that long).

> I selected a 3s1p Li-Po battery with 11.1 V. would it be better to get more cells for a higher voltage since the motors are 12 V?

It should be fine.  You could probably go to 4s if you're careful about not driving too much current to the motors.  With 4s they could run a bit fast if you drove them at full speed.  If they had the opportunity, this would make them suffer from shortened bearing life -- but you're not going to be running this day in and day out (I assume).

Comment: Tnx for all the answers. I will try to fit in a 4s. The application does not need large amounts of torque continuously and far from day and night. Tnx again for your help.